# Dropbox does not sync on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dropbox

For mysterious reasons dropbox is not working anymore.
I have added few small pdf to my folder and it is syncing them for hours.  I have tried to remove and reinstall dropbox but nothing is changed.

I suspect this can be due a possible recent ubuntu update.  Has anyone the same problem or now how to solve it?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, I removed the .dropbox hidden folder (located at home directory) and reinstalled Dropbox again.

But according to https://www.dropbox.com/help/72 you can reset ownership an permissions running the following commands:

```
sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"
sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-master
sudo chattr -R -i ~/Dropbox
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-master
```

Comment: Why this answer has been downvoted?

Comment: I am wondering that too.

Comment: your solution did not work for me. I have not the /dropbox-master folder.  Even removing  /dropbox-master from the previous code it is not working

Comment: Now it is working again. Maybe it was a problem of the dropbox server

Comment: I'm glad it's working again

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 with Dropbox 35.4.20 the folder ~/.dropbox-master does not exist anymore. Also this didn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. I ran dropbox from the terminal and it suggested to execute the following command to fix the problem, and restart dropbox:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```

It worked for me :-)

Comment: Just "run dropbox from the terminal" is the best way to find the problem.  Mine was out of disk space on that partition.

Answer (score 3):

First check whether Dropbox has been installed properly...

Run this command in terminal:

```
dropbox status
```

If the output is `Dropbox isn't running!`

Then run the following command:

```
dropbox start
```

Or if that doesn't work, try `dropbox start -i` to locate interpreter if possible.

Now Dropbox will start and automatically synchronize the updated files.

Fox next time you can run this command to start Dropbox automatically...

```
dropbox autostart
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a sync problem (16.04) which at least affects Dropbox uploading on `eduroam`, the WiFi where I work. Syncing does work when invoking Dropbox by terminal. To ensure upload, I've added

```
alias drop='dropbox stop && dropbox start && until [ "$(dropbox status)" = "Up to date" ] ; do dropbox status; sleep 1; done'
```

to my `.bashrc` file in my home folder. Running `drop` in terminal then stops and starts Dropbox and syncs, outputting status until finished. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: This was a good answer.  My problem was disk space (d'oh), but running this script helped me find it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if someone runs into such a problem:

I had the service stop working and so I updated to the latest version (currently 2.10.30). In ~/.dropbox-dist the main program has been changed from `dropbox` to `dropboxd` so my script in `/etc/init.d` had to be edited to reflect the change.

Line 4 in the popular Dropbox script should be

```
DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

(I ran into this problem in both Ubuntu 14.04 and 10.04, and 10.04 is still having problems, namely not syncing when a file is deleted and re-created.)

Comment: What do you mean by "popular Dropbox script"? I can't find anything that looks associated to Dropbox in my /etc/init.d folder.

Comment: Correct, there is no standard one. I'm still having problems on Ubuntu 10.04 but it works on 14.04.
[Here is the one I use from GitHub Gist.](https://gist.github.com/jaygooby/2948647)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything at https://www.dropbox.com/help/72 to no avail. The only thing that worked for me (Dropbox 2.10.30 under Ubuntu 14.04) was **plugging my computer to a wired internet connection**.