# Dropbox desktop app on Ubuntu 14.04 does not sync correctly

Tags: sync, dropbox

I've been using Dropbox for my development work (since I have 2 computers), and very recently I've noticed that any code that I write on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer does not sync to my mac. When I open the dropbox web app, it turns out that the new files/changes in existing files haven't synced to dropbox (web) itself.

I mean - all my code is stored in my dropbox folder itself, on both the ubuntu and mac computers. So there's no need to separately copy-paste files to the dropbox folder. The only way the sync finally works is when I restart the ubuntu computer at least twice. After the restart, the sync appears on both dropbox online, as well as the dropbox folder on the mac.

I've been through this question where the problem is that [Dropbox doesn't sync at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511486/dropbox-does-not-sync-on-ubuntu-14-04), but mine is different.

Interestingly, this problem seems to be happening more often on my ubuntu computer ever since Dropbox started popping up the ["Dropbox can't monitor the filesystem. Please run ..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148171/dropbox-error-echo-100000-sudo-tee-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches) notification. I did modify the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, but the changes(100000 instead of 8192) seem to be overwritten after every restart. And I'm not even sure these two problems are related.

Can someone please help.

Comment: I'm just wondering, have you consider using github or something simular for your codebase? Dropbox is a bad idea as a saving platform when developing anything really..

Comment: Yes, I already have my code on github repos and a git client on my mac, but in spite of several tries, I couldn't install a git client on the ubuntu computer. Any tips there?

Comment: Well that depends on that kind of error your getting when you try to install git via terminal?  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git`

Answer (score -1):

My Dropbox in my Ubuntu station was also unable to synchronize events....

What worked for me is:

- uninstall Dropbox
- Turn off the fire wall
- Install Dropbox
- Turn on the fire wall